# Implement star rating Angular

Tags: angularjs, rating

I am new to angular. I have an angular page. There is option for rating a particular user. But I dont know how to implement it? I will have the only code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-7 col-lg-12 no-padding">Overal Rating: 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o"> </span> 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o"> </span> 
   <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
</div>
```

Can any one help me to solve the issue?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/manishpatil/2fahpk7s/ and http://codepen.io/TepigMC/pen/FIdHb

Comment: I mean, in all pedantism, what you have isn't *code*, it's just *markup*.  In all seriousness, what do you believe that you have to do in order to address this?  I'll give you a hint: you need to produce N stars with a given value N and generate M-N blank stars to follow it.

Comment: Sorry makoto. I an not familiar with angular. I am a junior software programmer

Comment: It's hard to help you Sulu because all we see is HTML. Do you not have the .js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SSH gave a much better example in the jsfiddle linked in his comment under your question**

From what I can gather, and assuming you want to make something where the user clicks to give a # of stars(1-5), you can do something like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-7 col-lg-12 no-padding">Overal Rating: 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-ng-repeat="number in [1,2,3,4,5] track by $index" data-ng-click="setStars($index)" data-ng-style="litStars($index)"></span> 
</div>
```

...where setStars is a function the lets the user set the # of stars for his rating and litStars is a function that controls the CSS of the element, perhaps the background color or something.

in your .js file:

```
app.controller('yourApp', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.stars = 0;
    $scope.setStars = function(value){
        $scope.stars = value;
    };
    $scope.litStars = function(value){
        if($scope.stars>=value){
           return { "background-color" : "yellow" };
        }
        else {
           return { "background-color" : "white" };
        }
    };
```

Comment: It gives the result.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('yourApp', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.stars = 0;
    $scope.setStars = function(value){
        $scope.stars = value+1;
    };
    $scope.litStars = function(value){
        if($scope.stars>value){
           return { "color" : "yellow" };
        }
        else {
           return { "color" : "grey" };
        }
    };
```

Comment: i found some issues in vtange's code. so i made some changes. it works fine for me